# how can I delete When statement on this code (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
        val customerInfo = when {
            visitor.isCustomer -> customerService.getCustomerInfo(visitorId )
            else -> null
        }
```

In this Code, *visitor.isCustomer* is Boolean ( true / false)

Now then, I don't like specify **else -> null** into the code.
so i want to delete when statement and convert other ways..

How can I do that?
(I prefer to convert it with StandardKt (like let, apply, also... ))

Comment: Please look at my answer, Hope it helps you.

Comment: What don't you like about `else -> null`? You'll need to handle the case of non-customers _somehow_ (and this is probably about as clear and concise as any other way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an `if/else`

```
val customerInfo = if (visitor.isCustomer) customerService.getCustomerInfo(visitorId) else null
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

`val customerInfo = vistorId.takeIf { visitor.isCustomer }?.let { customerService.getCustomerInfo(it) }`

But I think a when or if statement is cleaner and more readable.
I think JetBrains coding convention would recommend an if statement instead of a when statement here.

Comment: I agree, the "oneliner" you provided works, but is not as readable as a simple if/else or a when statement.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with your advice. I just wanted to try several methods!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be more readable.

1. Without any additional things,

   ```
   val customerInfo = if (visitor.isCustomer) customerService.getCustomerInfo(visitorId) else null
   ```

With your own extension functions

2)Without infix: (condition).ifTrueElseNull{ return value}

```
inline fun <T> Boolean?.ifTrueElseNull(block: () -> T): T? {
        if (this == true) {
            return block()
        }
        return null
        }
    
        var a = visitor.isCustomer.ifTrueElseNull{customerService.getCustomerInfo(visitorId)}
```

3. With infix:  (condition) ifTrueElseNull{ return value}

   ```
   inline infix fun <T> Boolean?.ifTrueElseNull(block: () -> T): T? {
    if (this == true) {
        return block()
       }
    return null
    }

    var a = visitor.isCustomer ifTrueElseNull{customerService.getCustomerInfo(visitorId)}
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I checked your answer. The new method you gave is very interesting!!